# Simulate Multiple IP in C#

Tags: c#, .net, networking, ip

I want to do the same thing that is describe in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1309096/1547704 But in C# code.

Let me explain. I want to simulate a multiple IP on one computer dynamically. I want to permit to the user of my program to create dynamically clients with ip address define by himself.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Cant you use a proxy to do that ?

Comment: I don't want to change the IP of my Computer but to add IPs for the clients of my simulation. And i can't use proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using WMI. Check out [Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class. HTH

Comment: Do you think it's also possible with Netsh ?

Comment: I think so. You could use the "Netsh interface ip set" to create new IPs. Although I am not really sure what exactly are you trying to do here.